# How can I edit the filter in angular?

Tags: angular

How can I remove [this filter selection window](https://ibb.co/HpgG5Pw)?

That there would be only one "Contains" filter

I use Angular:

```
<kendo-grid class="k-grid-p" [data]="gridView"
  [pageable]="true" [pageSize]="gridState.pageSize"
  (pageChange)="pageChange($event)" [skip]="gridState.state.skip" 
  [sortable]="true" [sort]="gridState.state.sort"
  (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" [filter]="filter"
  [filterable]="true" (filterChange)="filterChange($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set columnMenu or  filterable propetry to false which will hide the filter for all the columns in grid

```
[columnMenu]="{ filter: false }
```

or

```
 [filterable]="false"
```

You could customize the filters as you want refer to

- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-hiding-row-filter-operators
- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-setting-the-order-of-the-filter-operators
- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/

Answer (score 0):

When I add this line `[columnMenu]="{ filter: false }"` it doesn't work

When i change `[filterable]="false"`. The search field disappears